# How do I skip a subprocess until it finishes

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program loops through this subprocess that returns server latency.

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
latency = subprocess.Popen(["ping.exe", "141.101.115.212"], 
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                           startupinfo=startupinfo)
latency = str(x.communicate()[0])
```

The problem is that the program will pause mid-loop to allow the subprocess to finish. Is there a way to skip this subprocess until it is finished so I may continue looping?

**edit**

The reason I can't just wait for the subprocess to finish is because I need to be able to click and drag the window the latency is displayed on. If the subprocess isn't finshed, the window will not move. This creates a lag effect.

```
class WindowDraggable():

    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label
        label.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.StartMove)
        label.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.StopMove)
        label.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.OnMotion)

    def StartMove(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def StopMove(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def OnMotion(self, event):
        x = (event.x_root - self.x - self.label.winfo_rootx() + self.label.winfo_rootx())
        y = (event.y_root - self.y - self.label.winfo_rooty() + self.label.winfo_rooty())
        root.geometry("+%s+%s" % (x, y))
```

Comment: is the result relevant to the rest of your code?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I am looping through this code so I can refresh the latency I display on a window. The problem is I cannot drag the window around while my program is waiting for the subprocess to finish. The subprocess is creating a lag effect. Do you understand me?

Comment: I think so, the results of the pings are used as output later in your program?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The ping displayed on the window is refreshed as soon as the new ping is made available by the subprocess.

Comment: why not just wait until the process is finished,if you are using the result later in the code you will have problems

Comment: Use a thread to communicate with the subprocess, and a queue to pass the resulting data to your main thread. And @PadraicCunningham I doubt you've understood the problem, OP is blocking his GUI thread thus his window becomes unresponsive.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Because I need to be able to click and drag the window the latency is displayed on. See the edit.

Comment: The real answer to this is to use threads as @l4mpi says, but Python's multithreading is notoriously bad. You may be better off using multiprocessing (there's a module for it, the syntax is almost identical and you  don't have to worry about the GIL (although that unlikely to be an issue in this use case))

Answer (score 0):

`latency` is bound to both the `subprocess` command and the converted output.  While it is the `subprocess` command you can use:

```
latency.poll()
```

to check if it has finished yet.  For more info, [check the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll).